# Is there a limit to start option in google custom api CSE list?

Tags: google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

using google custom API, I have a problem when I try to get results of more than 100.
I got an error as shown below. The code I am using is below:

```
res = service.cse().list(
    q='lectures',
    cx='my custom search engine id',
    num=10,
    start=100,
).execute()
```

I want to extract several pages every day.I got this error.

```
  HttpError 400 when requesting .. "Invalid Value">
```

if I make the start=90 or less it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for the Google Custom Search API:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest

> This role is not present if the current results are the last page.
>   Note: This API returns up to the first 100 results only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what is the best way to scrape the first 1000 results!!